# Is it possible to extract time from a text comment using js?

Tags: javascript

First let me apologize for my ignorance when it comes to js.

Is it possible to extract a time from text? For example, i'd like to extract the time from the following text "Results phoned by _ to _ at 2018/04/12 **01:31:33**. Results confirmed. Read back."

Is this even possible to accomplish this? The software that I use allows for both js and BIRT coding. Any help would be appreciated.

```
var str = dataSetRow["Comment - Result"];
var time = str.match(/([0-1]\d|2[0-3]):([0-5]\d):([0-5]\d)/g);
time;
```

Outputs to "Ljava.lang.Object;@bd6334" and i have no idea how to fix it.

I get the "Ljava.lang.Object;@" error for every row of my table with different characters after the @

If I change the code to:

```
var str = dataSetRow["Comment - Result"];
var time = str.match(/\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}/g);
if (time.length>0) time [0];
else "";
```

I get the desired result but it will only display 1 row of a table with significantly more rows. Am I missing something?

Comment: `str.match(/\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}/g)`

Comment: Sure, it's possible. But, that is really a question for Google, not Stack Overflow. If you have a ***specific*** coding question, post your code and ask away.

Comment: `Ljava.lang.Object;@bd6334` <- 1) Are you sure this is JavaScript and 2) If so, are you sure the response you're getting matches your example? This does not look like something JavaScript could have produced given the provided circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to get it working with some help from our system's manufacturer:

```
var str = dataSetRow["Comment - Result"];  
var time = null;  
if (str != null) time = str.match(/\d{4}\/\d{2}\/\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}/);  
var output = "";  
if (time != null) {  
  for (var i = 0; i < time.length; ++i) {  
    if (i > 0) output += "\n";  // this adds a line break in a computed column expression  
    output += time[i];  
  }  
 }  
output;
```